# CARTO - Performing cluster analysis on specific selection

Tags: postgis, cartodb

Is there a way to perform [cluster analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/calculate-clusters-of-points/%22cluster%20analysis%22) on a selection of a layer in CARTO? For example, if had data points throughout the U.S., and I wanted to know cluster of points in San Francisco, could I feasibly do (pseudo-SQL ahead):

```
SELECT ST_ClusterWithin(geom) FROM table
WHERE city = "San Francisco"
```

Or am I better off just splitting layers by city and then performing analysis on each layer in CARTO? I realize this option may not be ideal for ease of updating data across the layers. Any help is appreciate, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Filter by column value`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/filter-by-column-value/) to extract a selection of your table and then perform the cluster analysis on that analysis node. You can even drag  out the original dataset source to create a layer and perform again your analysis on another selection.

```
                         +---------+
                         | dataset |
            +------------+---------+----------+
            |                                 |
+-----------v------------+      +-------------v--------+
| name = "San Francisco" |      |    name = "New York" |
+-----------+------------+      +-------------+--------+
            |                                 |
            |                                 |
 +----------v---------+           +-----------v-------+
 |  cluster analysis  |           |  cluster analysis |
 +--------------------+           +-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you kindly!